# How to make TBB accept non-standard type of T for tbb::atomic<T>

Tags: templates, atomic, tbb

I am trying to set up an atomic vector, like

```
struct Vector
{
    double data[3];
};
```

and i wish it work atomicly in TBB. So I used

```
tbb::atomic<Vector> atomic_vec;
```

However, it failed to work, as the compiler stating `tbb::internal::atomic_impl<T>::my_storage` has incomplete type. I inspected tbb/atomic.h and found the relevant `tbb::internal::aligned_storage<Vector, sizeof(Vector)=24ul>` not specialized. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tbb::atomic` can be instantiated with types no greater than 64 bit as `tbb::atomic` designed to use "non blocking" hardware primitives. This is a limitation of vast majority of hardware TBB is intended to run on.

Comment: From the source code, it is recognized that the chip has to support atomic instructions like "compare and swap". This makes TBB limited to specified types. C++11 std::atomic does not have such limitation

Comment: When designing the tbb::atomic interface, we had a choice between supporting only operations that had reasonably widespread hardware support, or generalizing to operations that required extensive software support.  We decided to stay close to the hardware.  Note that on almost all current platforms, a C++11 std::atomic<Vector> will be implemented with a hidden lock, hence negating much of the benefit of atomic operations anyway.